# Make custom post types using ACF

Tags: plugins, custom-field

So I'm using the Genesis Framework with a theme provided by them, and I just implemented the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

What's the best way to create custom post types? I want to have a 'People' option that has the same UI as 'Posts' in that list shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that custom post types are a part of ACF. I use custom post type generators to add post types. [This is the one that I use](https://www.wp-hasty.com/tools/wordpress-custom-post-type-generator/). You would just need to paste the resulting code at the bottom of your theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score -1):

You need custom post type UI Plugin to create a post type like "posts"

Link - https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/